# Wordpress custom permalink is ignored

Tags: wordpress

I purchased a theme, which has the custom post type `talent` and now i'm attempting to have a custom permalink for this post type.

I've added this to functions.php

```
add_filter('post_link', 'talent_permalink', 99, 3);
add_filter('post_type_link', 'talent_permalink', 99, 3);

function talent_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    if (strpos($permalink, '%talent-cat%') === FALSE) return $permalink;
        // Get post
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        if (!$post) return $permalink;

        // Get taxonomy terms
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'talent_category');   
        if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms) && is_object($terms[0])) $taxonomy_slug = $terms[0]->slug;
        else $taxonomy_slug = 'all';

    return str_replace('%talent-cat%', $taxonomy_slug, $permalink);
}
```

I added `%talent-cat%` to the permalink settings custom structure and nothing is being changed.

What i want
`http://example.com/work/%talent-cat%/model/%postname%/`

What is currently happening
`http://example.com/work/talent/%postname%/`

How do i solve?  I want my code to permalink function to overwrite/have priority any plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need to change permalinks structures using **priority** (as you done) and

> register_post_type

, which allows to take any new structure for any post_type. I suppose the problem here is that you did not take into account this, so take a look to a [more clean approach](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53298/custom-post-type-url-rewriting).

It is hard going deeper in question, I suppose, without any knowledge about your theme. This because some premium themes does NOT allow to take into account these feature ("spaghetti code" and bad-formed structures / not conventional programming is very common there).

Please consider that you are working on latest URL version you working, in any case: i.e you can also force rewrite rules with this function:

```
flush_rewrite_rules();
```